# Minification and Uglification of modular Angular JS application for Production env

Tags: angularjs, node.js, bundling-and-minification, gulp-uglify

I have developed a simple login/registration application in angular 1.6 and want to minify before deploying it in prod env to improve performance and more importantly to secure it from reverse engineering threat. Here is my Project structure:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB9C4.png)

In index.js I am loading all my js files, angular related js files are inside resources while some js (jquery, bootstrap etc ) are in app-content/js folder along with another static content.

Wondering how minification/uglification/concatenation will pick files for the routes, here is the routing in my app.js:

[app.js routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaPdT.png)

Comment: I know it's not in the question, but have you looked into tools like `webpack`?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: My question is can we acheive this using grunt/gulp task , I tried gulp uglify task to minify and uglify but after packing my all js files in one single file my application is not working